# SQL Query to JOIN on field renames field in Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have an Access VBA program which joins two tables and stores them in another one.  My issue is that instead of the SQL query joining on `commonField` and having the new table with a `commonField` field, the new table has the `commonField` named `tableName1_commonField` and another named `tableName2_commonField`.

So, if the query was the following:

```
SELECT IIPM.*, UNIX.* INTO [UNIX_lob] FROM IIPM INNER JOIN UNIX ON IIPM.[appcode_0] = 
UNIX.[appcode_0];
```

Then the `appcode_0` field which is common between `IIPM` and `UNIX` becomes two fields named `IIPM_appcode_0` and `UNIX_appcode_o` in the new table `UNIX_lob` when I want it to remain a single field `appcode_0`.

I have traced this to right after the SQL Query is executed:

```
' Set the name of the new table where the joins will be stored. '
newTableName = "[" + tableName2 + "_lob]"

' Join tableName1 and tableName2 on commonField, and store the joined data in newTableName '
sqlJoinQuery = "SELECT " + tableName1 + ".*, " + tableName2 + ".*" & _
             " INTO " + newTableName & _
             " FROM " + tableName1 & _
             " INNER JOIN " + tableName2 & _
             " ON " + tableName1 + "." + commonField + " = " + tableName2 + "." + commonField + ";"
Debug.Print sqlJoinQuery
CurrentDb.Execute sqlJoinQuery
```

Comment: that would be expected behavior for Access VBA because you cannot have 2 columns named the same.  But what is your question?  why is it happening?  because the field name is repeated between the tables and you are selecting wildcard all columns.  How to stop it? Don't select all columns.  how to append rather than join? Use Union All

Comment: I was not aware that that is expected behavior and assumed that it was a mistake in writing my query.  Thanks - in that case, if I rename one of those columns, then that will suffice.

Comment: What Matt said.  There's not any real way to do that generically that I can think of, you're going to have to actually list out all your fields.  Well, maybe you can loop through the fields collection and write them all out to an array, but that sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: If create newTableName first using create table, then populate it with an insert statement, you will not need to rename a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing my comment above, I saw your other question, so I thought I would expand on what I said above a bit:

```
CREATE TABLE JoinTable (table1_key long null, table1_somecolumn text(50) null, table2_key long null, table2_somecolumn text(50) null);
```

Then having done this,

```
INSERT INTO JoinTable (Table1_key, table1_somecolumn, table2_key, table2_somecolumn)
SELECT t1.key, t1.somecolumn, t2.key, t2.somecolumn
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.key = t2.key
```

And this should do what you're after (albeit that no doubt your queries will look a bit messier than these!)

Hope this helps